# InnerBlocks breaks Flexbox and CSS Grid styles

Tags: block-editor

When using InnerBlocks so you can nest parent/child blocks you end up with additional HTML (in the editor) wrapping the child elements like so:

```
<div class="PARENT">
   <div class="block-editor-inner-blocks">
      <div class="block-editor-block-list__layout">
         <div class="block-editor-block-list__block wp-block is-selected">
            <div class="CHILD"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This causes a bit of a mess if using things like flexbox or grid on the parent element because it means the styles will instead apply to the `.block-editor-inner-blocks` instead.

e.g.

```
.PARENT {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 33%));
}
```

To get around this I've found myself having to do hacky overrides or write two different sets of CSS to handle the extra HTML that wraps the blocks in the editor:

```
.PARENT,
.PARENT .block-editor-block-list__layout {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 33%));
}
.editor-styles-wrapper .PARENT {
   display: block; /* remove grid in editor */
}
```

Is there a solution to avoid this? Or are you stuck with two sets of CSS or overrides when viewed inside the editor?

Comment: there's `useBlockProps` and `useInnerBlockProps` that can be used to eliminate the bulk of that markup if not all of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can eliminate the wrapping containers abandoning `InnerBlocks` and instead using the `useInnerBlocksProps` hook which is how the blocks that come with core do it. This will allow your block markup to match the frontend without the editor wrapping things in additional tags.

If we look at the official buttons block:

```js
import {
    BlockControls,
    useBlockProps,
    __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps as useInnerBlocksProps,
    JustifyContentControl,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
...

function ButtonsEdit( {
    attributes: { contentJustification, orientation },
    setAttributes,
} ) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps( {
        className: classnames( {
            [ `is-content-justification-${ contentJustification }` ]: contentJustification,
            'is-vertical': orientation === 'vertical',
        } ),
    } );
    const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps( blockProps, {
        allowedBlocks: ALLOWED_BLOCKS,
        template: BUTTONS_TEMPLATE,
        orientation,
        __experimentalLayout: LAYOUT,
        templateInsertUpdatesSelection: true,
    } );
...
    return (
        <>
...
            <div { ...innerBlocksProps } />
        </>
    );
}
```

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/buttons/edit.js

The blocks edit component eliminates the tags that surround the buttons block using `useBlockProps`, then passes the result to `useInnerBlocksProps` to do the same for its children. It also passes the parameters that it would have given to the InnerBlocks component as a second parameter.

This way it has full control over the markup of the block while still giving the editor the opportunity to add event handlers and other things.

Not that to use this, you must declare you use the v2 API when registering the block. If you don't then `useBlockProps` won't work

```js
"apiVersion": 2,
```

A more minimal example:

```
import {
    useBlockProps,
    __experimentalUseInnerBlocksProps as useInnerBlocksProps,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

const Edit = ( props ) => {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps( {} );
    const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps( blockProps, {} );
    return <div { ...innerBlocksProps } />;
};
```

This also has the benefit of avoiding a common bug in block validation where the innerblocks component shares a tag with another element, and the whitespace generation causes validation to fail, which isn't possible here

Comment: also noting that while the hook is in an experimental namespace, it's been used on all core blocks since WP 5.6 with little to no change in API

Comment: Does this only work with JSX as we don't use that to avoid having to transpile the code.

Comment: Ah it looks like it does. However it's not working with the `InnerBlocks` and still generates that wrapper HTML: 
`el('div', { ...blockProps },
    el(InnerBlocks, { ...innerBlocksProps })
)`

Comment: Those are set like this: `const blockProps = useBlockProps( { className: 'staff-list' } );
const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps( blockProps, { allowedBlocks: ['staff-list-item-block'] } );`

Comment: Have I missed a trick with the use of it on `InnerBlocks`? Works fine on the parent element with `useBlockProps` from the looks of it.

Comment: It can work without JSX, but I have never used it that way so I'm unsure of the appropriate syntax. Note that you should not use the old InnerBlocks component, the hook is a replacement, not an enhancement

Comment: Ah.... that's super confusing. So turns using `el('div', { ...innerBlocksProps })` alone will in fact generate both the parent and inner blocks code using the correct classes.

Comment: yes, `innerBlocksProps` contains everything from `useBockProps` too, `el('div', { className: 'staff-list', ...innerBlocksProps } )`. If it didn't, you'd need a minimum of 2 components, one for the blocks props and one for its children, otherwise they might conflict and it'd be unclear which would win out

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that I've lost the ability to move and delete the `staff-list-item-block` blocks within the parent now... dunno if that's a bug in the experimental innerBlocksProps or something I've done. But when I click on them I don't get the usual toolbar to move/delete etc...

Comment: that should not be the case, but I can't advise on the cause since I can't see your code for either block. I should also note the example in my last comment should not have contained the `className` attribute, that should instead have been passed into the `useBlockProps` hook

Comment: Yeah it's weird. If you have time here's the two blocks: https://pastebin.com/cTpcSSFt - Your help with this has been much appreciated!

Comment: hmm both of those blocks are lacking a namespace, the block editor refuses to register them, but once I prefixed them with `test/` that started working. The reason you can't select the parent block is because its root element does not have the necessary props so there's no way to put a selection class or add the event handlers etc. If I modify it to use `return el('div', { className: 'row', ...blockProps },` then I can select it

Comment: Also this article is useful https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-edit-save/

Comment: I figured it out. I had to add the blockProps to the child block as well. So seems once you use this new props stuff you need to add it the any of the blocks you want to use as children of it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way it can be done without breaking block selection etc:

```
const blockProps = useBlockProps();
const innerBlocksProps = useInnerBlocksProps();

<div { ...blockProps }>
  { innerBlocksProps.children }
</div>
```

Comment: Note I had trouble getting the InnerBlocks to save their content, so I ended up showing innerBlockProps.children only if the block was unselected, and the normal <InnerBlocks /> when selected. Sure, Flexbox is broken when entering content, but as soon as the user selects another block it visually snaps back to the proper layout.